# Como colocar um título abaixo do bar button iten

Tags: swift, icons

Queria saber como colocar um título abaixo do ícone no toolbar, já tentei de algumas formas mas sem êxito.
Já tentei via código e nas propriedades do ícone no menu lateral direito.

Comment: Poderia postar um trecho do código que você já tentou? Facilitaria os usuários a enxergar o problema melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o que você quer fazer dá bem pra resolver direto no editor.

1) Selecione o botão e abra a aba Size Inspector (Régua)

2) Na categoria Title Insets ajuste o atributo Top para um valor que o texto esteja na posição desejada.